# The most effective way to run parallel CLI processes from PHP application

Tags: php, multithreading, image-processing, parallel-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to find the best way to run multiple ImageMagick CLI processes from the PHP code.

I'm using ImageMagick as a CLI utility because I have to do complex and intense image processing. It's more convenient than writing tons of corresponding PHP code using the Imagick extension.

The task is to take a huge GIF file containing many (50-100) frames and process all these frames as fast as possible. So, if we have a server with 16 CPU cores, we need to process 16 frames simultaneously.

Solutions I see:

1. The most simple: to perform all processing using the PHP `exec` function with an ampersand at the end of the commands, e.g.

```
exec('convert frame1.gif ...some_params... frame1_output.gif &');
exec('convert frame2.gif ...some_params... frame2_output.gif &');
exec('convert frame3.gif ...some_params... frame3_output.gif &');
...
```

After this, we only have to wait for the required amount of output files in the output directory.
Will this approach utilize CPU cores correctly?

2. To use some sort of event-driven asynchronous processing PHP framework, e.g. [Amp](https://amphp.org/). Internally it uses `libev` and `libevent`. **I'm not sure if it's a good idea to start CLI processes using an event loop.**
3. To use [Parallel](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.parallel.php)
4. To use some sort of task queue with the producer and many consumers (workers). Each worker will be a separate PHP process. This approach leads to overhead with the message broker or some other kind of queue implementation, deploying, network delays while processing etc...
5. To use some process manager e.g. [PHP-PM](https://github.com/php-pm/php-pm) or Supervisor just for spawning ImageMagick processes.

Which approach seems to be the most correct for you?
What other ways are there to solve this problem?

Comment: IMHO, it seems very unlikely that creating a whole process for every frame, that reads the GIF file and processes it and writes it back to disk is the optimal route for this - though it would depend on the size of the GIF and the complexity of the processing. You will also presumably have to re-assemble a GIF at the end and re-optimise the palette(s)?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I will have to re-assemble a new GIF file from the processing results eventually. But I guess it doesn't relate to a parallel processing problem. What could you suggest as a replacement to processes? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

For tasks like that... if you don't have to use PHP i would go for NodeJS here. Simple async task would do that for you

Comment: "Async" and "Parallel" are not equal. NodeJS is async but single-threaded, and my question is about parallel processes (and the right way to start them).